# Prove $\frac{d \ln(y)}{d \ln(x)} = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{x}{y}$ using limits

Tags: real-analysis

I see this equation used again and again in economics but I really can't find a rigorous limits based proof.

I have that

$$\frac{d\ln(y)}{d\ln(x)} =  \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\ln(f(\ln(x)+h))-\ln f(\ln(x))}{h}$$

Not sure how to finish. Thanks

Comment: I'm interested in why do you need this in economics?

Comment: Elasticity. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_(economics)

Comment: For example in a regression ln(y)=a+bln(x)+e, dln(y)/dln(x) = b => 1% increase in x causes a 1% increase in y

Comment: I understand that I don't and likely won't understand. Thanks, though.

Comment: Because it is easier to deal with relative changes than absolute especially when comparing changes that have different units.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the limit solution, I thought of how it would work. It is true for $g$ differentiable with a nonzero derivative that

$$\frac{df(x)}{dg(x)}= \frac{\frac{df(x)}{dx}}{\frac{dg(x)}{dx}}$$

Proof: the RHS =  $$ \lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{g(t)-g(t_0)}=\lim_{t \to t_0} \frac{{f(g^{-1}(g(t)))-f(g^{-1}(g(t))})}{g(t)-g(t_0)}$$
which is the definition of the derivative of f at t with respect to g(t). To see this, note that if u=g(x), $$ \frac{df}{du}= \frac{{f(g^{-1}(u))-f(g^{-1}(u_0)})}{g(t)-g(t_0)} = \frac{{f(g^{-1}(g(t)))-f(g^{-1}(g(t))})}{g(t)-g(t_0)}$$

The result desired follows from this formula.

Answer (score 4):

Let $z = \log x$, i.e. $x = \exp(z)$, and $y = y(x)$ be a smooth and nonzero enough function of $x$; then
$$\frac{d \log y(z)}{dz} = \frac{1}{y(z)} y'(z) = \frac{1}{y(z)} y'(x(z))x'(z) = \frac{dy}{dx} \frac{x}{y}$$ where we use the chain rule twice.

Comment: How do you go from the 2nd to 3rd equality? Maybe I'm not getting you're prime notation. When I see $y'(z)$ I think $\frac{dy}{dx}$ evaluated at the point z. So $y'(z)=y'(e^x)$

Comment: The chain rule says that $y'(x(z))x'(z) = (y(x))'(z)$. I understand the latter as $y'(z)$, where $y$ is a function of $z$.

Comment: @Kevin Given that $y = y(x)$, the only way I see to understand $y$ as a function of $z$ is $y = y(\exp(z)) = y(x(z))$. This lends itself to the chain rule.

Comment: Correction on my comment. $y'(z)=y'(ln(x))$ ... still thinking on your solution. Thanks!

Comment: Here's where my confusion lies: By chain rule $\frac{dy}{dz}(y(x(z))=y'(x(z))x'(z)$. But in the argument, we have $y'(z)=y'(x(z))x'(z)$, and at least from the way I am interpreting the notation, $y'(z)\ne \frac{dy}{dz}(y(x(z))$ since $y'(z)$ is $\frac{dy}{dz}$ evaluated at z, not x.

Comment: I think its probably just that I am not seeing something, I guess that is why I was hoping to see it via limits since there wouldn't be ambiguity in notation that way

Comment: @Kevin I only claim that $y'(x(z))$ is $\frac{dy}{dx}$. If we expand formally, $y'(z) = (y \circ x)'(z) = y'(x(z)x'(z)$. A priori $y$ is not a function of $z$ and this must be clear - we only define it thus in the sense the $y$ is a function of $x$, which is in turn a function of $z$. IMO this is a source of (slight) non-rigour in the question being asked in the first place.

Comment: I finally got it thanks

Answer (score 1):

Implicit assumptions in your question:  $y = f(x)$, $x > 0$, $y > 0$.  With these, the following calculation is valid:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{d \ln y}{d \ln x} &= \frac{d \ln y}{dx} \cdot \left(\frac{d \ln x}{dx}\right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{1}{y}\frac{dy}{dx} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)^{-1} \\
&= \frac{x}{y} \frac{dy}{dx}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: How come you can manipulate the dx's this way? Whats the rigorous argument behind that